# Как реализовать высчитывание прошедшего времени между датами из текстового документа в Python

Tags: python

Имеется файл, где находятся даты формата :

2018-02-11 22:58:50.762515

2018-02-11 22:59:19.270131

Нужно импортировать их из документа, и просчитать прошедшее время между ними.

Импорт из файла реализовал, а вот с отниманием проблема

код:

```
now=linecache.getline('time.txt', i)
before =linecache.getline('time.txt', i-1)
print(now)
print(before)
delta=now-before
print(delta.days)
```

суть ошибки:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Заранее спасибо за помощь)

Comment: в какой часовой зоне время указано?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> s = '2018-02-11 22:58:50.762515'
>>> d = datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
>>> d
datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 11, 22, 58, 50, 762515)
>>> d1 = datetime.strptime('2018-02-11 22:59:19.270131', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
>>> d1 - d
datetime.timedelta(0, 28, 507616)
>>>
```

Comment: это вернёт неверный результат, если  к приему переход с зимнего на летнее время в промежутке между указанным временем произошёл. [Find if 24 hrs have passed between datetimes - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26313520/4279)

Comment: Наконец то переборол, всем спасибо за помощь)